# How to make a fully independent module in a Gradle multi-project

Tags: gradle, git-submodules, modularity

I want to develop a piece of software in java with some GUIs on top (in particular, an android app). I would like the core functionality to be a self-contained module that is fully independent from any GUI or other software layer that could be built on top.

The core module is a Gradle project itself:

```
core
├── src
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

For the app, it is included as a git submodule in a root repository:

```
project
├── app
│   ├── src
│   └── build.gradle
├── core
│   ├── src
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

Since the core module is independent and has its own repo, I have to be able to treat it as a Gradle root project; hence it has its own `settings.gradle`. But when I work in the root project, I want it to behave as a subproject of the latter (so that running `gradle` in the `core` directory recognises it as the `:core` subproject using the `settings.gradle` in the parent directory). And without changing the contents of `core` (which will be a git submodule).

I don't want to make a separate branch in `core`'s git repo in which there is no `settings.gradle`, because in that branch the repo wouldn't make sense on its own, and, again, `core` shouldn't "need to know anything" about the root project.

The ideal solution would be an alternative version of git submodules in which custom changes to the submodule could be committed to the parent repo alone without affecting the submodule's original repo. (With the ability of merging upstream changes in the submodule with the local commits.) Then I would add one such "local" commit that removes the `core/settings.gradle` file.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution here is to develop all modules as completely separate projects with independent Git repos. Then use Maven to import the `core` library into `project`. You should even consider publishing `core` to a private Maven repository that you can add to your `build.gradle` file in `project`.